# Write text in a random location automatically

Tags: javascript, text

I've looked around stackoverflow and I found **[this](http://tinyurl.com/nageoar)** JSFiddle that partially has what I need. All I need is a pre-determined word (the participant doesn't enter their desired word), and I need it to do this automatically over set intervals.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    var fullWidth = window.innerWidth;
    var fullHeight = window.innerHeight;
    var text = "predefined string";
    var elem = document.createElement("span");
    elem.textContent = text;
    elem.style.position = "absolute";
    elem.style.left = Math.round(Math.random() * fullWidth) + "px";
    elem.style.top = Math.round(Math.random() * fullHeight) + "px";
    document.body.appendChild(elem);
}, 1000);
```

Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6eTcD/34/).